# apply TOP function only to % values

Tags: excel

[execelsheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSbJL.png)
need help regarding, COLUMN K HAS  values and values with % sign. i am trying to apply TOP 10 function only to values in percentage i.e having % sign .
tried by using FIND FUNCTION ON column k, value with % sign then copy values with % sign to next column. to next column apply TOP FUNCTION.

[sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaIBb.png)

Comment: The `%` is just a formatting. A formula will do the same with `100%` as it would with `1` as it is the same. However: you "could" use `LEFT(CELL("format",A1))="P"` which is only true if the number format is set to `%`. And because `CELL` does not work in an array way, you would need a helper column. Also possible: if the layout does not change, you can use something like `IF(MOD(ROW(K10:K20),2),K10:K20,MIN(K10:K20))` which will turn all numbers with even row numbers to the smallest value of the whole range (just inside the formula)...

Comment: formula not working, ,ionere excelsheet1, new sheet posted.

Comment: The formula is just a part of the solution. I assumed that there is already a "TOP 10" formula and you simply need to alter the input values.

Comment: ignore excelsheet1,new sheet posted

Comment: i need to compare values in percentage only i.e with % sign

Answer (score 0):

Your percentages are on the 5th, 7th, 9th, etc rows.

In N9:O9 (per supplied image) as,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(K$4:INDEX(K:K, MATCH(1E+99, K:K)))/(K$4:INDEX(K:K, MATCH(1E+99, K:K))=O9), COUNTIF(O$9:O9, O9))-1)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, K$4:INDEX(K:K, MATCH(1E+99, K:K))/MOD(ROW(K$4:INDEX(K:K, MATCH(1E+99, K:K))), 2), ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

Comment: not able to apply, can it done with conditional formatting, just like TOP function works